# Sending a sockaddr_in struct through socket

Tags: c, sockets

How can i send a `struct sockaddr_in` through a socket? 
I'm trying that way but it's not working

Client

```
sprintf(message, "%hu %hu %lu %c", server.sin_family, server.sin_port, server.sin_addr, server.sin_zero);
send(sock , message , 16, 0);
```

Server

```
recv(client_sock , convert , 16 , 0); 
sscanf(convert, "%hu %hu %lu %s", &my_addr.sin_family, &my_addr.sin_port, &my_addr.sin_addr, &my_addr.sin_zero);
printf("%hu %s %lu %s", my_addr.sin_family, my_addr.sin_port, my_addr.sin_addr, my_addr.sin_zero);
```

Just want to send my_addr structure to the server, why client does not receive it properly?

i.e. by sending

```
sin_family = AF_INET
sin_port =   8888
sin_addr =  "127.0.0.1"
sin_zero = (NOT SETTED)
```

I have in stdout

```
sin_family = 2                 //enum AF_INET == 2
sin_port =   45346
sin_addr =  "127.0.0.1"
sin_zero = X
```

`sin_family` and `sin_addr` are ok. 
`sin_port` is not correct. What's wrong? (I don't care much about sin_zero).

Thanks for your cooperation!

Comment: You aren't using `ntohs()` on the port at the receiving end, but why are you doing this? The peer already knows who you are.

Comment: Client asks the server through tcp to send him an udp socket of another client to allow client-client communication, good hint the ntohs!

Comment: @EJP very helpful! Thank you